# Can I store query result of one field into different variables? if not then what should I do for that?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This code shows the output as `subject1 subject2 subject3 subject4` but I want to store that values in different variables (like `$s1=[1],$s2[2],$s3[3],$s4[4]`) so I and use them in different functions what should I do? can any one help please...

Comment: Why'd you delete the code?

Comment: $query=mysql_query("select `subject` from `markssub1`  where `sname`='$user' AND `sid`='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $subject=$row['subject'];  
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("select `subject` from `markssub1` where `sname`='$user' AND `sid`='$id'");

$subjects = [];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $subjects[] = $row['subject'];  
}

foreach($subjects as $subject){
    echo $subject . '\n';
}
```

Comment: you loop an array to build a new array - whats the point in that?

Comment: I modified OP's original code. He didn't seem to have a grasp of PHP variables. I added the `foreach` to show how he can make a new array with only the values he wants.

Comment: dear your modified code is showing error on line 3.. is any thing need to modified?